# How to create pdf files in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

I want to create pdf files in drupal .module file.

I have view of bulk operations in which I have added an operation send pdf file and download pdf file.
I want to get some data from the database and and create a pdf file from it and when I select an operations it should create and send the pdf file in an email.

So how could I do this???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a quick search at [Drupal Modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules)  I found [this](http://drupal.org/project/print) module. And I also found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-php/) by Googling. The latter one seems to need no additional PHP modules and should be easy to integrate.

Answer (score 5):

You should look first in the PHP library for creating PDF files. You can use TCPDF or many others in the PHP libraries:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php

Comment: +1 For TCPDF, it's actively developed (maybe a bit too active for some :p) and is a very easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new module named [PHP WK HTML to PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpwkhtmltopdf)

From his site:

> This is intended for module developers, nothing is usable from the
>   front-end.
>
> This module is a Drupal Library implementation for the PHPWkHtmlToPdf
>   wrapper and as a result is extremely small because it uses WkHtmlToPdf
>   to do the heavy work.

And you can use if you want [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf)

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field
>   of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the
>   administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is
>   added.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the module [print](http://drupal.org/project/print). This module allow you to print a node but also any page of your site. After enable the module you can generate pdf simply by visiting url starting with printpdf/NID or printpdf/AnyPAth.

To generate the pdf it can use the following libraries: dompdf, TCPDF, wkhtmltopdf.

Follow the [installation guide](https://drupal.org/node/306882)

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF is good for pdf creation.

There is new module [TCPDF](https://drupal.org/project/tcpdf). See tcpdf_example submodule to get started.

For installation see INSTALL.txt:

1. Download and install libraries module.
2. Download TCPDF library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/
3. Extract it to sites/all/modules/libraries.
4. Download and install TCPDF module.
5. Check the status report to verify if the installation was successful.
6. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very intricately styled view recently that I just couldn't get looking the same as a pdf, I used this service to do it and I was pretty impressed. http://www.html2pdfrocket.com/